# How to pass props to two tables with the same component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a question about the component panel in react

Currently, I have a requirement to create a common component for the **Order** and **Product** **tables**. But the two tables have different numbers of columns, one side has many columns and one side has few columns, besides there are also different table names.

I have a piece of code like this

```
import React from 'react';
import {Table, Image} from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../Table/index.css';
import Button from '../Button/index';

const TableItem = ({productList}) => {
  return(
    <Table striped bordered hover>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No. </th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {productList.map((product, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{product.id}</td>
            <td><Image src={product.image} /></td>
            <td>{product.name}</td>
            <td>{product.category}</td>
            <td>{product.price}</td>
            <td>
              <Button variant="success" onClick={redirectToEdit}>Edit</Button>
              <Button variant="danger" onClick={deleteProductItem}>Delete</Button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
}

export default TableItem;
```

That code I have created for the product table, but the order table is not because I do not know how to do it properly. I named fixed for the column, I know this is wrong because the order table will also retrieve components from this table, so I can not make the name like that

The order table also has the following columns: Username, address, quantity, status .....

**How can I change the code in this component that can be used for both tables**
Can anyone help me to explain for this, thank you so much

Comment: You can create one generic table. And use it in both Order and Product. Generic table should consist props i.e you can send from parent to show or not. And expect a props which send table column name which render in Generic table

Answer (score 1):

So you can do something like this, create a table component and pass the columns list and data in there as props that way you can control the table from the parents component and can be used in any way as you want.

```
 const TableItem = ({data, columns}) => {
  return(
    <Table striped bordered hover>
      <thead>
        <tr>
           { 
             columns.map((column, index) => {
               <th key={ index }>{ column.name }</th>
             }
           }
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.map((product, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{product.id}</td>
            <td><Image src={product.image} /></td>
            <td>{product.name}</td>
            <td>{product.category}</td>
            <td>{product.price}</td>
            <td>
              <Button variant="success" onClick={redirectToEdit}>Edit</Button>
              <Button variant="danger" onClick={deleteProductItem}>Delete</Button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
}
```

and in the parent component you can do something like

```
const parentComponent = () => {
  return {
    <TableItem columns={ productColumns } data={ productData } />
    <TableItem columns={ orderColumns } data={ orderData }
  }
}
```

**Note** Code not tested and is pseudo

Comment: If I have many data, How should I write in data={productData}? Example: <TableItem columns={["No.", "Image", "Name", "Category", "Price", "Action"]} 
          datas={["1", "https://place-hold.it/100x150", "MIlk tea", "Milk tea", "100000", "button"]}
        /> . In that I just have one data, but if I have many what should I do. Thank so much

Comment: i dont understand fully what do you mean by many data. do you have multiple sources where data is coming from ? can you show me some sample of the data that you have ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass columns (Array) as a props and render it.

```
const columns = ['username', 'quantity', 'etc'];
    const TableItem = ({List, columns}) => {
      return(
        <Table striped bordered hover>
          <thead>
            <tr>
             {columns.map((name, index) => (
                 <th key={index}>{name}</th>
             ))}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
        </Table>
      )
    })
```

If you have some common columns then you can pass one more props commonColumns like that.

```
const TableItem = ({List, columns, commonColumns}) => {
  return(
    <Table striped bordered hover>
      <thead>
        <tr>
         {commonColumns.map((name, index) => (
             <th key={index}>{name}</th>
         ))}
         {columns.map((name, index) => (
             <th key={index}>{name}</th>
         ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    </Table>
  )
})
```

Hope this will help you.